# SQL Group by 2 column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to display once in multiple rows with the 2 GROUP_BY

My table is like this

```
    +----+----------+-------+
    | ID | BRAND |   TYPE    | 
    +----+----------+-------+
    |  1 | A     |  Clothes  | 
    |  2 | A     |  Hat      | 
    |  3 | A     |  Hat      | 
    |  4 | A     |  Hat      | 
    |  5 | B     |  Jeans    | 
    |  6 | B     |  Jeans    | 
    |  7 | B     |  Hat      |
    |  8 | C     |  Clothes  |
    |  9 | C     |  Jeans    |
    | 10 | C     |  Jeans    |
    | 11 | C     |  Hat      | 
    +----+-------+-----------+
```

And my query like this

```
SELECT brand, 
       type, 
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM store  
GROUP BY brand, type
```

When I run that query the result is

```
        -----------------------------
        | BRAND |   TYPE    |  TOTAL |
        -----------------------------
        | A     |  Clothes  |   1    |
        | A     |  Hat      |   3    | 
        | B     |  Jeans    |   2    |
        | B     |  Hat      |   1    |
        | C     |  Clothes  |   1    |
        | C     |  Jeans    |   2    |
        | C     |  Hat      |   1    |
        ------------------------------
```

Thats not the result I expect. I just wanna display once `Brand` and with the following `Type` also display once if there are multiple same value.

UPDATE: expect result

```
        -------------------------------------------
        | BRAND |   TYPE                |  TOTAL |
        -------------------------------------------
        | A     |  Clothes, Hat         |   4    |
        | B     |  Jeans, Hat           |   3    |
        | C     |  Clothes, Jeans, Hat  |   4    |
        -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Comment: Italien not possible if you want to show both the columns `brand` and `type`. If you group the column `brand`, what do you expect to be in the `type` column since there are multiple (different) values that are grouped together?

Comment: @jarlh updated question

Comment: If the `type` is integer is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using [`Group_Concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with `Distinct` clause, you can get all different and **unique** type(s) in a comma separated string, under a `brand` group.
- Use [`Sum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function to calculate the total

Try the following:

```
SELECT brand, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type) As type, 
       SUM(total) AS total
FROM store  
GROUP BY brand
```

Comment: Edit : Oh here it is! This work fine with my code! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggests me to do conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT brand, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Clothes' THEN TYPE END) AS Clothes,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Hat' THEN TYPE END) AS Hat,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Jeans' THEN TYPE END) AS Jeans
FROM store s
GROUP BY brand;
```

If you want to one row with multiple types then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT brand, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT TYPE) As TYPE, COUNT(total) AS total
FROM store s  
GROUP BY brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

with this you get olny one type per brand

SELECT brand, 
      Max( type) AS  type, 
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM store
GROUP BY brand